# Application.GetResourceStream in non-ui thread

Tags: multithreading, silverlight, resources

I have a problem with Silverlight application.

Suppose I have an xml file in resources stream. I get it as usual with something like this:

```
StreamResourceInfo sr =
    Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("uri goes there", UriKind.Relative));
var xml = XElement.Load(sr.Stream, LoadOptions.SetBaseUri);
```

And everything works just fine. But if the same code runs in the background thread (via async/await or, to be simple, in background worker) it always returns null.

I’ve heard about a bug in VS with similar problems (returning null) so I’ve tried to clean solution, delete obj folders etc. but nothing works — in background thread this code always return null for resources stream.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  Your code works fine on a background thread.  GetResourceStream would normally return null when the specified Uri is not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access UI resources in background thread. Ideally you should access it in UI thread and pass it to background thread.

Comment: Ok then, back to original question: is it possible to to declare a resource in such a way that it won’t be treated as an _UI_ resource (maybe some other build action in file properties) so it could be accessed from background thread?

Comment: The `GetResourceStream` is not accessing a UI resource.  I see no reason why the original code in the question shouldn't work.

Comment: Yep Anthony, you’re right: I’ve made a sample solution and it works just fine even in other thread. Looks like the problem lies down within resolving corresponding loader class through Unity — will dig into that.

Comment: Nope, nothing wrong with unity — I’ve referenced loader class explicitly but still that code running on the same thread returns requested resource and just right after in background thread the same code returns null (even if it wrapped in Dispatcher.Invoke()). I’m running out of ideas why the hell this is happening.